# rails: Error with HABTM and ActiveRecord (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, psql

So, I have these two models:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
end
```

And the join table migration is:

```
class CreateJoinCityCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration    
  def up                                
    create_table :cities_companies do |t|                        
      t.integer :city_id                                                                    
      t.integer :company_id                                                                 
    end                                                                                     
  end                                                                                       

  def down                                                                                  
    drop_table :cities_companies                                                            
  end                                                                                       
end
```

I'm trying to find companies based on a city ID:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @companies = Company.includes(:cities).where('city.id' => params[:city_id]).references(:cities)
      render :text => @companies.inspect
  end
end
```

And What I get is:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "city"
>   LINE 1: ...cities"."id" = "cities_companies"."city_id" WHERE
>   "city"."id... ^ : SELECT "companies"."id" AS t0_r0, "companies"."name"
>   AS t0_r1, "companies"."category_id" AS t0_r2, "companies"."url" AS
>   t0_r3, "companies"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "companies"."updated_at" AS
>   t0_r5, "companies"."image_file_name" AS t0_r6,
>   "companies"."image_content_type" AS t0_r7,
>   "companies"."image_file_size" AS t0_r8, "companies"."image_updated_at"
>   AS t0_r9, "cities"."id" AS t1_r0, "cities"."name" AS t1_r1,
>   "cities"."state_id" AS t1_r2, "cities"."created_at" AS t1_r3,
>   "cities"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "companies" LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   "cities_companies" ON "cities_companies"."company_id" =
>   "companies"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" =
>   "cities_companies"."city_id" WHERE "city"."id" = '14'

I tried a few things, like casting the parameter to int, but I need some help to figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `where` clause.

You are referencing `city.id` when it should be `cities.id` as the table name is city.

An even nicer way of writing it would be to use the hash syntax

```
Company.includes(:cities).where(cities: { id: params[:city_id] }).references(:cities)
```